# How to export max queue size to Excel?

Tags: java, anylogic

I am simulating a production line in Anylogic, consisting of seven generic processes.

The main blocks I use in my model are: seize, delay and release. During the running of the model, queues are created (increase and decrease) all the time.

My question is: how should I save the max value of each queue in my model and time duration of it and then export it to excel file?

I tried to use the the data set and the statistics fetchers icons, but these only present the changes of the queues during the running.

Answer (score 1):

#### Retrieve the maximum value

Use the [Statistics element](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fconnectivity%2FExcel_File.html) to record statistics about your queue size (such as max, min and so on) periodically (default: once per second):

[image: Statistics Element]

You can retrieve the maximum that this statistic element recorded by calling:

```java
myStatistics.max();
```

You could output this value for example by writing the following code in the *On destroy* code of Main:

```java
traceln(myStatistics.max());
```

#### Export to Excel

In order to export something to Excel, add the Excel module from the *Connectivity* palette and set it to an existing Excel file.

As described in the [documentation of the Excel module](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fconnectivity%2FExcel_File.html), the command to write a single value to Excel is the following:

```java
void setCellValue(<type> value, int sheetIndex, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
```

In your case, put this in your *On destroy* code of Main:

```java
excelFile.setCellValue(myStatistics.max(),1, 1, 1);
```

[image: Excel export]